# Deep Learning fit error (the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.)

Tags: deep-learning, keras, kaggle

I'm new to Deep Learning. I'm trying to follow along with the [fast.ai](http://fast.ai) lecture series, and trying to reproduce the work manually in a Kaggle kernel.

I'm trying to work through cats vs. dogs Redux in Kaggle. I'm not concerned with accuracy, I just want to get something working.

I'm using Keras and the VGG16 model, as outlined in the fast.ai course. [I'm also leaning on code outlined in this article to get me off the ground](https://medium.com/@curiousily/tensorflow-for-hackers-part-iii-convolutional-neural-networks-c077618e590b).

[This is my Kaggle notebook.](https://www.kaggle.com/thekevinscott/dogs-vs-cats-w-vgg16/editnb)

I'm encountering an error when trying to fit my model that I don't know how to interpret:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-596f25281fc2> in <module>()
     12 #model.fit(input[0].transpose(), output[0].transpose())
     13 
---> 14 model.fit(X, Y, epochs=100, batch_size=6000, verbose=1)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.1.2-py3.6.egg/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1591             class_weight=class_weight,
   1592             check_batch_axis=False,
-> 1593             batch_size=batch_size)
   1594         # Prepare validation data.
   1595         do_validation = False

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.1.2-py3.6.egg/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_batch_axis, batch_size)
   1428                                     output_shapes,
   1429                                     check_batch_axis=False,
-> 1430                                     exception_prefix='target')
   1431         sample_weights = _standardize_sample_weights(sample_weight,
   1432                                                      self._feed_output_names)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.1.2-py3.6.egg/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
     81                 'Expected to see ' + str(len(names)) + ' array(s), '
     82                 'but instead got the following list of ' +
---> 83                 str(len(data)) + ' arrays: ' + str(data)[:200] + '...')
     84         elif len(names) > 1:
     85             raise ValueError(

ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 24500 arrays: [array([[1],
       [0]]), array([[1],
       [0]]), array([[0],
       [1]]), array([[1],
       [0]]), array([[1],
       [0]]), array([[1],
       [0]]), array([[1],
       [0]]), array([[0],
     ...
```

Here's some more information:

```
X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3)
Y = [i[1] for i in train]

> type(X)
numpy.ndarray

> X.shape
(24500, 50, 50, 3)

> type(Y)
list

> len(Y)
24500

> Y[0]
[1 0]

> model.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_7 (InputLayer)         (None, 50, 50, 3)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 50, 50, 64)        1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 50, 50, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 25, 25, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 25, 25, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 25, 25, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 12, 12, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 12, 12, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 12, 12, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 12, 12, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 6, 6, 256)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 6, 6, 512)         1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 6, 6, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 6, 6, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 3, 3, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 3, 3, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 3, 3, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 3, 3, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 1, 1, 512)         0         
=================================================================
Total params: 14,714,688
Trainable params: 14,714,688
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

And the model:

```
model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols, img_channel))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=100, batch_size=6000, verbose=1)
```

I've googled around but I'm at a loss for how to interpret this. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47445588/keras-functional-model-with-multiple-inputs?rq=1) seems similar, and seems to indicate that the output is the problem, but I'm not sure how that would apply to me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply transform your Y to a numpy array with shape (24500, 2):

```
Y = np.ndarray(Y)
```

Comment: I then get "ValueError: sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32" - any idea what that means?

Comment: @thekevinscott Ah yes it doesn't work if you have more than 32 sub-arrays inside the list. You should create a numpy array with the mentioned shape and fill it manually with the labels, during dataset loading time.

Comment: The tutorial I'm following uses the file names to generate a one hot array ([0, 1]) representing "dog, cat". I'm generating the labels as an np.array, which appears to be the same thing as an ndarray? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879315/what-is-the-difference-between-ndarray-and-array-in-numpy)

Comment: I've also updated my question with the model.summary(), though I don't see where the Y (labels) input is being defined within the model?

Comment: @thekevinscott I think you're trying to create a ndarray from a list of ndarrays instead of a list of lists. Use np.concatenate instead to concatenate a list of numpy arrays and you should be good to go

Comment: I think that got me closer but I'm getting a new error. I now have Y as a numpy array, and it's shape is (24500, 2). The error I'm getting is: "Error when checking target: expected block5_pool to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (24500, 2)". Can you help me decipher what this means? My interpretation is it's asking for something akin to the shape of X (which is 4 dimensions - 24500, 50, 50, 3) - but I would expect Y to be 24500 rows of 2 elements each (one hot labels), which it is. Clearly I'm missing something here.

Comment: @thekevinscott Your model is wrong, it does not have a Dense layer that outputs two classes. You should add that and it will work.

Comment: It was indeed wrong, thank you! That got me over the finish line