# Error when checking model input for validation data in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, cross-validation

I have a model defined as such:

```
model = Model(inputs=[inputs, y_true, is_weight], outputs=[y_pred])
```

I want to specify the training and validation data, since I am performing k-fold cross-validation and I have predefined the splits beforehand.
I fit the model as follows:

```
model.fit([X_train,  Y_train, wgt_map_train], batch_size=1, epochs=200,
              validation_data = [X_val, Y_val, wgt_map_val],
                    callbacks = [checkpointer, earlystopper])
```

The shapes of the input both for training and validation are the same, except for the first dimension:

```
X_train.shape = (6732, 12, 86, 98, 1)
X_val.shape = (765, 12, 86, 98, 1)
etc.
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
~/miniconda3/envs/segment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    970                 val_x, val_y,
    971                 sample_weight=val_sample_weight,
--> 972                 batch_size=batch_size)
    973             if self._uses_dynamic_learning_phase():
    974                 val_ins = val_x + val_y + val_sample_weights + [0.]

~/miniconda3/envs/segment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    749             feed_input_shapes,
    750             check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 751             exception_prefix='input')
    752 
    753         if y is not None:

~/miniconda3/envs/segment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    100                 'Expected to see ' + str(len(names)) + ' array(s), '
    101                 'but instead got the following list of ' +
--> 102                 str(len(data)) + ' arrays: ' + str(data)[:200] + '...')
    103         elif len(names) > 1:
    104             raise ValueError(

ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 3 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[[[[0.        ],
          [0.        ],
          [0.        ],
          ...,
          [0.        ],
          [0.        ],
          [0.        ]],

         [[0.        ],
          [0. ...
```

If I remove validation_data and I replace it for validation_split = 0.1 works, but then this would not be an adequate way of doing k-fold CV. Thanks!

**EDIT**
I have also tried adding 'validation_batch_size = 1' in model.fit, but then I get prompted with:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-eefd2297c992> in <module>
     42               validation_data = [X_val, Y_val, wgt_map_val],
     43               validation_batch_size = 1,
---> 44                     callbacks = [checkpointer, earlystopper,tb])
     45     time2=time()
     46 

~/miniconda3/envs/segment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    940             epochs = kwargs.pop('nb_epoch')
    941         if kwargs:
--> 942             raise TypeError('Unrecognized keyword arguments: ' + str(kwargs))
    943         if x is None and y is None and steps_per_epoch is None:
    944             raise ValueError('If fitting from data tensors, '

TypeError: Unrecognized keyword arguments: {'validation_batch_size': 1}
```

I have checked similar posts like:
[Deep Learning fit error (the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48360816/deep-learning-fit-error-the-list-of-numpy-arrays-that-you-are-passing-to-your-m) and
[Keras functional model with multiple inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47445588/keras-functional-model-with-multiple-inputs?rq=1)

Comment: I see your y in fit is None... can you try this: validation_data = ([X_val, Y_val, wgt_map_val], None)

Comment: what do you mean y? Are the labels not specified in Y_val after all?

Comment: yes the labels, I don't see in your code the format model.fit(X, y, ...). I don't know if passing a list on [X, y, w] is what you want